# What is the meaning of "put in place"

Tags: phrase-meaning

http://www.shanghaidaily.com/metro/public-services/More-security-measures-put-in-place-at-Shanghais-2-airports-over-terrorism-fears/shdaily.shtml

More security measures **put in place** at Shanghai's 2 airports over terrorism fears

What is the meaning of "put in place" in the above context. What can be used instead of "put in place" there.

Comment: You may want to see this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140680/is-put-in-place-a-correct-english-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> More security measures **put in place** at Shanghai's 2 airports over terrorism fears

Here 'put in place' might mean 'to bring into effective action'. Thus, **Deployed** could be a possible substitute for the phrase.

You could also use **were implemented** to substitute the phrase, as in

> More security measures **were implemented** at Shanghai's 2 airports over terrorism fears

Answer (score 1):

Put in place means to place something, and in this case to place more security at the two airports. 
for more help, refer to this link for synonyms(similar words and phrases) and antonyms (words or phrases which mean the opposite.).[thesaurus.com- put in place synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/put%20in%20place)